# Synonymise [eclipse-emf] with [emf]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emf) and [eclipse-emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf) seem to be synonyms:

Description for [emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emf): "For questions about the Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) project. EMF is a modeling framework and code generation facility for building tools and other applications based on a structured data model."

Description for [eclipse-emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf): "Use this tag for questions about the Eclipse Modeling Framework Project (EMF)"

I suggest to declare [eclipse-emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf) a synonym of [emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emf). However, I do not have the privilege to make a synonym suggestion on these tags.

Comment: Alternative proposal: create [eclipse-modeling-framework] (26 characters) and synonymize both to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the [25 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bemf%5D+-%5Beclipse%5D+-%5Bjava%5D+-%5Beclipse-emf%5D+-%5Bxtext%5D+is%3Aq+-%22eclipse%22+-%22model%22&mixed=0), that were seemingly unrelated to eclipse EMF and found out that all of them except one were related to eclipse EMF. The one question was related to Hibernate's Entity Manager Factory, which I tagged with [hibernate-entitymanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate-entitymanager) instead.

Once this clean up was done, I created the synonyms. I used [eclipse-emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf) as the parent, as it was more descriptive, and also because it was already proposed that way by Zoltán Ujhelyi on Jan 11 '13. The tags are now synonyms:

[emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emf) (× 445) → [eclipse-emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf) (× 433)